# dynamically giving data to list

Tags: android, list, button

Im new to android im desingnig one app description is...
i have kept one edit text and one button whenevr i click on the button i have to store that value in a list... i tried like this 
I didnt get where theerror is....

```
  public class Dynamic extends Activity {


 ArrayList<Getters> x=new ArrayList<Getters>();



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.nameok);
    final EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name=ed.getText().toString();
            Getters y=new Getters(name);
            x.add(y);
            ListView lv= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            Demo demo=new Demo();
        lv.setAdapter(demo);

        }
    });




}
public class Demo extends BaseAdapter
{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return x.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.forlist, null);
        }
        //View v=LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.forlist, null);
        TextView listname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.listname);
        listname.setText(x.get(position).name);

        return v;
    }

}




public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
   }
```

getters..

```
 public class Getters {
public Getters(String name) {

    this.name = name;
}

String name;

public String getName() {

     Log.v("name---",""+name);
    return name;

}
```

}

Comment: what error are you writing about ? what is 'Demo' ?

Comment: im getting null pointer exception after clicking the button and demo is the class used to implement baseadapter

Comment: i want to store the data from edittxt

Comment: and you didn't think that was worth mentionning ? also, you don't think the stacktrace could help ? (did you read it, btw ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please First [see this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) and then implement your code so its easy to implement.

**Edit :**

http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/

Hope you will get idea about how to manage list data dynamically.

**Edit**

Just write below code for add event in List view

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name=ed.getText().toString();
            your List_view_obj.add(name);
            //call adapter class and pass that string                
           your List_view_obj.setAdapter(your adapter's obj);

           your_adapter_obj.notifyDataSetChanged();



        }
    });
```

Hope you got it.

Comment: can i hav a  example to get the data from edit text and store it in list

Comment: thanx i did it but im getting error in this place listname.setText(x.get(position).name);

Comment: actually i didnt hav enough reputations to vote this im soo sorryyy

Comment: I have a small doubt whenever i press button i have to apperar a edit text and button in that activity only can i knw how to do it

Comment: you can hide the view like list_obj.setvisibility(View.Gone) or Hide as per your needs.

Comment: yaa i got it thanq u helping me lot for my small app

Comment: Chintan sorry to ask these many questions i have another doubt while im pressing back button the prvious list was getting deleted can i have answer for this....plzzz

Comment: may be you are clearing the list any were or calling onCreate() again if its true then resolve it. it should not be wrong

Comment: i have my code once check it    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766914/when-im-pressing-back-button-my-list-items-are-getting-deleted/14767112#14767112