# When im pressing back button my list items are getting deleted

Tags: android, back-button

In this activity i was trying to store data dynamically but when im pressing back button in my emulator my list items are getting deleted.....

This is my main activity...

```
      public class Dynamic extends Activity {

    Button bt,bt2;
    EditText et,et2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameok);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);

        final String input = et.getText().toString();

        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (et.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    CharSequence text = "Enter Your Name";
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                    toast.show();
                } else {
                    if (et.getText().length() == 0) {
                        Context context = getApplicationContext();
                        CharSequence text = "Enter Your Number";
                        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                    et2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    bt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                      bt2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            String input = et.getText().toString();
                            String input1 = et2.getText().toString();
                            Intent in = new Intent(Dynamic.this, GetList.class);
                            in.putExtra("input", input);
                            in.putExtra("input1", input1);
                            startActivity(in);


                        }
                    });

                }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
        bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberok);

    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is my list where im giving
List:

```
  public class GetList extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ListView lv;
    Button bt3;

    ArrayAdapter<String> a_adapter;
    ArrayList<String> x_listItems;
    ArrayList<String> y_listItems;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameok1);
    bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent in3=new Intent(GetList.this,Dynamic.class);
            startActivity(in3);
        }
    });

    x_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    y_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

    a_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, x_listItems);

    lv.setAdapter(a_adapter);

    Intent in = getIntent();

    String inp = in.getStringExtra("input");
    String inp1 = in.getStringExtra("input1");

    if (null != inp && inp.length() > 0) {
        x_listItems.add(inp);

        a_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    if (null != inp1 && inp1.length() > 0) {
        y_listItems.add(inp1);
        Log.v("num", ""+y_listItems);


    }
}

     }
```

Comment: are you passing another value and put it on your ArrayList because  when you click the back button coming from your second activity the value on the EditText will be retain since you did not finish your Main Activity

Comment: yaaa im passing only another variable

Answer (score 1):

Try to declare all variables out of your oncreate method..

```
    public class GetList extends Activity {
     ListView lv;
        Button bt3;

        ArrayAdapter<String> a_adapter;
        ArrayList<String> x_listItems;
        ArrayList<String> y_listItems;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        bt3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nameok1);
        bt3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in3=new Intent(GetList.this,Dynamic.class);
                startActivity(in3);
            }
        });

        x_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        y_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();

        Intent in = getIntent();

        String inp = in.getStringExtra("input");
        String inp1 = in.getStringExtra("input1");

        if (null != inp && inp.length() > 0) {
            x_listItems.add(inp);

            a_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (null != inp1 && inp1.length() > 0) {
            y_listItems.add(inp1);
            Log.v("num", ""+y_listItems);


        }

         a_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, x_listItems);

         lv.setAdapter(a_adapter);
    }


}
```

Comment: i got it u said that we have to give all variable in oncreate right with that we have to create object also in create thnaqqqqq

Comment: hey can i know one thing how to come homebutton when i pressed back button on emulator

Answer (score 1):

if you press back button when your on your GetList Activity the value of your ArrayList will be delete because the Activity is Destroy if you want to retain the value of the ArrayList make them

```
ArrayList<String> x_listItems;
ArrayList<String> y_listItems;
```

to this

```
public static ArrayList<String> x_listItems;
public static ArrayList<String> y_listItems;
```

Comment: thanx fro the answer i tried but actually the prvious values are deleting and placed with the value that entered

Comment: can anyone help me for this

Comment: well i try to code the one that you are doing and it's working on me making static variable will retain its data;try to log this.
Log.v("num", ""+x_listItems.toString());
Log.v("num", ""+y_listItems.toString());

Comment: actually its replacing the previous ones the previous values are not staying and if it is done my project will be completed i stuked with thisss....:(

Comment: log is printing and im unable to enter second value into the list

Comment: please send me the whole project in rar file here's my email bikinipants20@yahoo.com i will try to see whats your problem

Comment: hey i got it thanqqqqqqqq soooooooooooo muchh

Comment: hey can i know one thing how to come homebutton when i pressed back button on emulator

Comment: just destroy or finish all the activity and you can go to the homescreen :)

Comment: its not completed when i tested it its not updating the list i when i press edit it should it be edited and updated but its not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with this:

Just remove this two lines from OnStart and paste at OnCreate. I just say this according to android lifecycle. Removing OnStart is even better

```
et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.number);
bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.numberok);
```

and I found some mistake in your code:

```
          if (et.getText().length() == 0) {
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Enter Your Name";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
        } else {
            if (et2.getText().length() == 0) { // you noticed this as et
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                CharSequence text = "Enter Your Number";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                toast.show();
            }
```

Comment: no there it is not wrong my team lead said that we have to save the list by intents but im not getting correct procedure